# how to handle primary key existence for a random string key in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-insert

A random string (6 char) is used to be the primary key in my SQL database table. However, i don't know how to handle the error and re-insert the query to the database.

What is the best solution which will re-insert the sql query to the database with another random string key? (doing the re-insert in catch block?)

```
try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                con.Open();
                    var key = RandomString(6);
                    SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tableName(d1, d2, d3) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", con);

                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("0", key));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("1", "values"));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("2", DateTime.Now));
                   var rowCount = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


                con.Close();
                if (rowCount < 1)
                {
                    label.Text = "OMG it is Fail :(";
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    label.Text = "HEY ~~~ inserted";
                    return true;
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                label.Text = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
```

The above code is written in C#, but i don't think the problem is C# only. Therefore, it is welcome for another programming language :)

Comment: how is the `random` key generated ?

Comment: @Squirrel it is a method  which will return  a 6-chars string in 0-9, a~z and A~Z

Comment: Rather than trying to mask the symptoms of a poor design, your time would be much more wisely spent changing your primary key (which is obviously meaningless since it's random) to something sensible like an identity or uniqueidentifier. You could even have a computed column generate a 6-character representation of an identity if you need backward compatibility (even just hex would give you 16.7 million unique values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered executing a SELECT query first with the random string? If that then returns no results, run the INSERT. Otherwise, generate a new random string until no results are returned.

===

Edited for code sample.

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    int count = 1;
    string key = string.Empty;

    while (count > 0)
    {
        key = RandomString(6);
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE d1 = @0", con);
        selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("0", key));
        count = (int)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tableName(d1, d2, d3) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", con);

    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("0", key));
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("1", "values"));
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("2", DateTime.Now));
    var rowCount = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


    con.Close();
    if (rowCount < 1)
    {
        label.Text = "OMG it is Fail :(";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        label.Text = "HEY ~~~ inserted";
        return true;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    label.Text = ex.Message;
    return false;
}
```

===

To be honest, the method above that I'm showing is pretty bad. It solves your problem of collisions in the primary key, but it's not the **right way** to do it. I would recommend one of a number of changes:

- Change the Primary Key in the table to a GUID. This will allow you to use `Guid.NewGuid()` for that value, which you can assume is unique.
- Change the Primary Key in the table to an auto-incrementing integer. Then, in the code that inserts, **do not** supply a value for that column. This will allow the database to handle the primary key for you.
- If you **must** use the random string as the primary key, I would do a query against the table for all primary keys during application initialization, and store that result in a static `HashSet<string>`. Then, when you generate a new random string in the `RandomString(int)` method, check against that HashSet to see if it exists yet. If it does not, continue with the insert, otherwise generate a new one.

Comment: The problem is that the error is thrown in the catch block, not in try block. I don't have enough ability to work with Block-To-Block communication...

Comment: @kingyau I am not advocating working with any errors. Change your functionality to do a SELECT query against your table's primary key with the generated random string. If it does not exist, do your INSERT.

Comment: @kingyau - I added a sample piece of psuedo-code for clarity.

Comment: wow, i thought that you are talking about `do {inserting} while (success)`.. yours is more better than i thought . many thanks :)

Comment: @kingyau - I added more comments, as this method of check-and-insert isn't very performant and is essentially poor database design. Hopefully they bring you some clarity on the correct solution, rather than the "right for me" solution. If this solution has answered your question, please mark it as accepted and upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

Computing a random value and testing it against the database is a slow/non-scalable way to do this - it amounts to guessing an available value. The more values are used, the worse the odds of guessing an available value, and the slower the process will become.

If you really cannot use Identity or Sequence or GUID for this, I saw a great suggestion in another thread to just make a table containing a "pool" of unique values, and use them. Each time you generate an object, select from this table and delete the row so that value is no longer available.

Be sure to use a transaction correctly, that blocks other concurrent readers from getting the same value.

Comment: +1, but you would need to wrap the whole operation in a transaction and set the transaction isolation level to serializable.

Comment: Definitely needs a transaction. I think select with tablockx and holdlock hints also works. Basically the read and the delete both need to block other readers.

Comment: Edited to incorporate that

Comment: With this, make sure you are refilling the pool on occasion, to ensure that it never runs out (assuming you're not populating it with every possible combination upfront). This refill job will have the same problem as your original problem, looking for unique unused values, but at least it would be in a separate process instead of every time you do an application transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try the following

Have the Try/Catch block in a loop with a flag

Set the flag in the the Catch block to continue the loop if there is any error.

Comment: what loop do you suggest? i only know how to use if-else and for loop..

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use stored procedure ?

So generate the random key in the stored procedure (use something like GUID, use the last 6 character or something like that).

Then in that same stored procedure, before you insert the id, you do a check first by doing exists statement. If ID exists, then re generate ID, if not, then insert.

So your c# code will only called that stored procedure. Doing an insert or any sql statement in c# is bad because it's prone to sql injection.

Comment: "Doing an insert or any sql statement in c# is bad because it's prone to sql injection" is both misleading and wrong. SQL Injection occurs when you don't parameterize your queries. As the OP is doing this correctly in the code example, your statement does not hold weight.

In other news, SQL in C# is neither bad nor good, but a separate way to handle a solution.